# What is the average number of iterations calling (rand() % range) in order to receive a specified number within range?

Tags: c, random, time, iteration, time-complexity

Lets say you have a function:

```
int GetNumOfIterations(int highest_num, int num_in_range)
{
    int temp = -1;
    size_t i = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    while (num_in_range != temp)
    {
        temp = rand() % highest_num;
        ++i;
    }

    return i;
}
```

What will be the time complexity of it? In worst and average cases?
What will be the average for 'i'?

An interviewer told me the average of iterations is the range's size, so if range is 0 to 100, the average of iterations is 100. Why? Is this the correct answer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Think about it: What's the span of possible numbers `rand() % highest_num` can return? You want one specific number, so your probability of hitting that number on any given iteration (presuming that your RNG is unbiased) is one out of that-many.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question about theory, and Stack Overflow is limited to _practical_ questions -- questions about how to go about the practice of programming.

Comment: BTW, `rand() % highest_num` _isn't_ unbiased, unless `highest_num` divides equally into the largest possible number that `rand()` can return. I don't think your interviewer expected an answer that went into that much detail, but I'd be impressed by an interviewee who was able to discuss the effect that had on the result.

Comment: In the worst case, `highest_num` and `num_in_range` both exceed `RAND_MAX` and the loop never terminates. :-)

Comment: Even without that, the worst case is unbounded. There's no guarantee that a random number generator will generate all numbers in the range in any particular number of repetitions (although if the repetitions is many times the range size, it would be reasonable to suspect bias if it doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

> What will be the time complexity of it? In worst and average cases? What will be the average for 'i'?

This simple answers the interviewer is looking for, at least initially, are that the worst case is unbounded (with a true random number generator) or bounded by the period of the generator (with a practical finite-state pseudo-random number generator) and that average is (about) `highest_num`. More detailed answers are discussed below.

Assuming a pseudo-random number generator of at least minimal quality, it should generate every value within range eventually. Since these generators are finite-state machines, they go through a cycle with some period *P*. If they have *N* bits for their state, *P* ≤ 2<sup>*N*</sup>. *N* may be 32 for simple generators. I suppose it may even be 16. On the other hand, it could reasonably be 1024, in which case your computer will fail physically before it runs through 2<sup>1024</sup> samples.

Let *R* be `RAND_MAX`+1. Since you wrap `rand()` modulo `highest_num`, there are ceil(*R*/`highest_num`) or floor(*R*/`highest_num`) values of `rand()` for which `rand() % highest_num` would produce the target `num_in_range`, according to whether `num_in_range` is less than `R % highest_num` or not, respectively. Therefore, the worst case is at most *P*+1−ceil(*R*/`highest_num`) or *P*+1−floor(*R*/`highest_num`), respectively.

For the average run length, let *L* be the average and *p* be the probability of the target value. Assume all samples are independent. Then *L* satisfies *L* = *p*•1 + (1−*p*)•(1+*L*), and simple algebra shows *L* = 1/*p*. If `num_in_range` is less than `R % highest_num`, then *p* = ceil(*R*/`highest_num`) / *R*. Otherwise, *p* = floor(*R*/`highest_num`) / *R*.

Of course, with a finite-state pseudo-random number generator, the samples are not independent. The fact we have just had one or more samples that do not hit the target indicates we are partway through the generator’s cycle, and the number of samples that do hit the target is more dense in the remaining period. Discussion of how this affects the average is left as a further exercise.

Comment: Assuming the RNG cycles through all values and is seeded properly, wouldn't the average iterations be `highest_num / 2`?

Comment: @dbush: If `highest_num` = `RAND_MAX+1`, then the lengths of the runs to the various values range from 1 to `highest_num`, so, by symmetry, the average is (1+`highest_num`)/2. However, consider `RAND_MAX`+1 = 4 with a period of 4, so the numbers generated are in some permutation of [1, 2, 3, 4]. Let’s consider all the potential cycles used by a generator, [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4, 3], and so on. With `highest_num` = 2, we will hit the target of 1 whenever `rand()` returns 1 or 3. Counting the resulting run lengths in the permutations, you will see the average length is 1⅔, not 1½.

Comment: @dbush: Further, a generator could have a period *P* greater than `RAND_MAX`+1. (For example, it could cycle through some internal permutation of `SUPER_RAND_MAX`+1 numbers and return its internal number modulo `RAND_MAX`+1.) As *P* / `highest_num` increases without bound, the generator behaves more and more like one in which the samples are independent, so its average run length must approach that of the independent-sample model, `highest_num` rather than (`highest_num`+1)/2.